# Jest Mock nor working as expected throws an error

Tags: unit-testing, axios, jestjs, mocking, automated-tests

```
const axios = "axios";

jest.mock(axios);

axios.get.mockImplementation((url) => {
    if(url === process.env.ENHANCED_CLAIM_STATUS_276_DETAILS){
        return Promise.resolve({ status: 200, data: claim_response_276 });
    }
    if(url === process.env.ENHANCED_VALUE_ADDS_277_DETAILS){
        return Promise.resolve({ status: 200, data: claim_response_277 });
    }
});
```

i am trying to mock the api responses but it throws this error :

```
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mockImplementation')**
```

Answer (score 0):

The `moduleName` parameter should be a **string**.  See API doc [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

An working example:

```js
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock('axios');

describe('74929332', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    axios.get.mockImplementation((url) => {
      return Promise.resolve({ status: 200, data: 'claim_response_276' });
    });
    const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api')
    expect(result).toEqual({ status: 200, data: 'claim_response_276' })
  })
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74929332/index.test.js (14.419 s)
  74929332
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.559 s
```